# Canvas not visible in my GearVR Project with Vuforia (Unity)

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, augmented-reality, vuforia

I created a simple AR project with vuforia and my Samsung GearVR, like described here : https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Integrating-Gear-VR-and-the-AR-VR-Sample-in-Unity-5-3-and-above . This works fine so far. Now I want to add some canvas elements, I don't want them to move, just fixed canvas elements. I tried to place my canvas on different positions in the scene :

- Root
- Child of CameraRig
- Child of LeftCamera
- Child of TrackableParent
- Child of an ImageTarget in TrackableParent

But for all of these cases the canvas is not visible. I know, this question is really specific, but maybe someone with knowledge in this specific thing can help me.

This is my Canvas :

[image]

Comment: what type of canvas are you adding ? Can you provide some screenshots to further illustrate your problem ?

Comment: Sure, but since it's a Unity project there is just one canvas right? Screenshot coming soon.

Comment: Canvas has 3 types as far as I know and in my current project I have a ScreenSpace, a ScreenSpace-Camera and two worldSpace canvases.

Comment: I was more interested in the inspector view of the actual canvas, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Oh wait this is the inspector view of the working version, but the canvas in this version is cut off extremely, so I was hoping for a better solution. The not working version had "Screen Space - Camera" set

Comment: so you managed to get the canvas to render on screen after all but its not in the right place ? generally for VR project I use a Word Space canvas with a shader that always keeps it on top. A screen space canvas will not work that good because there are two screen in VR headset itself right ?

Comment: Yeah I got it working after I posted the question. Because of the 2 cameras I have duplicated my canvas and attached one to each camera for the moment but the scale is not correct, the placement seems to be alright.